# 'django.db.backends.posgresql_psycopg2' isn't an available database backend

Tags: django, postgresql

I am stuck at setting up django with postgreSQL.
I have installed required packages for setup provided below.

```
asgiref==3.5.0
Django==4.0.2
djangorestframework==3.13.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
```

and have edited `DATABASES` in `manage.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.posgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tododb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '2993',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

but getting error when i runserver or make migration:

```
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.posgresql_psycopg2' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old database `ENGINE` name that was deprecated. Try this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'tododb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '2993',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

It's what the error says. Also, `postgresql` was misspelled as `posgresql` (missing a `t`). I've always thought PostgreSQL should rebrand to an easier name!